# Auth0 Forget last login

Tags: authentication, auth0

How to forget the remembered last login?
Since I think with last login remembered, it's easy to hack the previous user logged in on the same computer.
I tried to close and reopen the browser, but still, it remembers the last login.

Answer (score 3):

Auth0 keeps a session for the logged user. You can alter the **SSO Session Timeout** in the tenant's settings page, under the [Advanced tab](https://manage.auth0.com/#/tenant/advanced) (the default value is 7 days).

If you want to clear the user's session, you can use the [logout endpoint](https://auth0.com/docs/logout), redirecting the user to:

```
https://your-auth0-domain/v2/logout
```